# When is the reverse time stochastic process Markov?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

I'm reading the paper "[Time Reversal of Diffusions](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-14/issue-4/Time-Reversal-of-Diffusions/10.1214/aop/1176992362.full)" by Haussman and Pardoux.
The authors begin with a diffusion process in $[0, 1]$ via the SDE $dX_t = b(t, X_t) dt + a(t, X_t) dw_t$ where $w$ is a Wiener process and $a, b$ are sufficiently nice determinisitic functions.

They define $\bar X_{t} = X_{1 - t}$ and in the first sentence of their main proof on page 1190 they say "... since it is already known that $\bar X_t$ is a Markov process..."

**Edit:** The comment below made me realize I was confusing Markov and Martingale properties. This was my original confused comment.

> How do they know $\bar X_t$ is a Markov process? In fact, isn't the
> statement false under the filtration generated by $\bar X_t$? If we
> set $X_0 = 0$ deterministically, we know that this pins the terminal
> point of $\bar X$, in which case, $E[\bar X_1 | \bar X_t ] = 0$ for
> all $t \in [0, 1]$, violating the Markov condition.

Now with the correct definition of Markov property, let me update the question.

Let $\mathcal{F}_t$ be the filtration generated by process $X_t$. Similarly, let $\bar{ \mathcal{F}_t}$ be the filtration generated by $\bar X_t = X_{1 - t}$.  The authors' claim seems to be, for $t_0 \le t$ that $E[\bar X_t | \bar {\mathcal{F}}_{t_0} ] = E[\bar X_t | \bar X_{t_0}]$. Does this follow from $X_t$ being Markov?

**Edit 2:**
I'm seeing that the authors say in the very first sentence "It is well known that a Markov process remains a Markov process under a time reversal." I guess it's just always true, but I don't see it from the definition of Markov process.

For reference, here is the definition of Markov process that appears in Karatzas and Shreve.
[image: definition of Markov process]

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the very definition:

> $X$ is Markov if its future values and the past values are independent given the present value.

It is symmetric with respect to time reversal, so a time-reversed Markov process is Markov.

Having a fixed value in "the future" does not violate the Markov condition, as a constant is independent from anything. For example, Brownian bridge is a Markov process, moreover, a diffusion.

Comment: Thanks -- I was confusing "Markov property" with "Martingale property!" I'm thinking about the time symmetry still. If we have $E[X_{t'} | \mathcal{F}_t ] = E[X_{t'} | X_t]$ for $t > t'$, I'm not sure it implies the reverse time analogue.

Comment: @Mark, it doesn't.

Comment: Then how can the authors conclude that $\bar X_t$ is Markov?

Comment: It is a time-reversed Markov process.

Comment: I think the authors are claiming that $\bar X_t$ is Markov, which I still don't see. I might be missing something obvious here... I updated the question.

Comment: @Mark, I guess we're walking in circles. A time-reversed Markov process is a Markov process.

Comment: Haha I think we are. But let me try one more time. The Markov property is that the future is independent of the past, given the present. In the filtration formalism, $E[X_{t'}|\mathcal{F_t}] = E[X_{t'}|X_t]$ for $t < t'$. To show that the reverse property is Markov, we need to show $E[X_{t'}|\sigma(\{ X_s \}_{s \ge t})] = E[X_{t'}|X_t]$ for $t' < t$, i.e. the past is independent of the future, given the present. The second condition does not seem to follow automatically from the first.

Comment: @Mark, "In the filtration formalism..." no. You're confusing Markov and martingale properties once again.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the definition of Markov process